# Centos 7 Error getting repository data for development, repository not found

Tags: centos, repository, development

I'm using Centos 7 and get "Error getting repository data for development, repository not found".

Comment: Your question contains precious little information. Could you please add more context to this issue, such as what command you used when this error occurred, along with any relevant configuration that you may have changed from the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** you tried to perform a yum install, i.e. `yum install somepackage`, and yum repos.d does not have an entry for EPEL (extra packages and dev stuff) so yum is letting you know it has no idea where to look.

Configure the files in dir: `/etc/yum.repos.d/`  Each file in that dir are for contacting different yum repositories.

[This link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/) shows you how to add the EPEL repository to your `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.